# MapKit and custom classes

Tags: ios, header, mapkit, ios4

I created a Custom Class that stores some data.

One piece of data that I want to store is

CLLocationCoordinate2D

What headers do I need to include to be able to use/store this data type?

I thought it was MapKit and when I add the following lines to my Person.h file, i get errors

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
```

Error: MapKit.MapKit.h No such file or directory

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D gpsData;
```

Error: Expeected specificier-qualifier-list expected before 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'

Comment: have you import framework for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the documentation for CLLocationCoordinate2D reveals that that type is declared in CLLocation.h. You should add the CoreLocation framework to your project and `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error...

> Error: MapKit.MapKit.h No such file or
>   directory

Indicates that XCode cannot find the MapKit.h header file on its build path.  You need to include the MapKit framework in your application.  To do so in XCode 4+ ...

- Open your XCode Project (double click on the project file)
- Select your application target (you'll likely have one which matches the application name)
- Choose the 'Build Phases' tab for the target
- Click the + button in the 'Link With Libraries' section
- Search for 'MapKit' and select it

You may need to add the framework for any other target that needs to link with MapKit i.e. a tests target.

Comment: I already added the framework with Xcode 4.01 (latest version). My ViewController has MapKit and no errors. I add MapKit to my custom class and the errors occur.

Comment: Have you tried adding the #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h> in the file in question then?